# Arduino ide not declared in scope problem

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

**Hello I am making radio controler for tank but I have problem with joystick code. Every time when I had same problem with ('JR' was not declared in this scope) in Serial.print('JR'); line. I don't have a lot of experince with arduino so it can be easy to solve problem. Can somebody help me?
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
#define K10 14
#define K11 15
#define JRY A2
#define JRX A3
#define JLY A4
#define JLX A5

void setup() {

  pinMode(K10, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(K11, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(JRY, INPUT);
  pinMode(JRX, INPUT);
  pinMode(JLY, INPUT);
  pinMode(JLX, INPUT);

  bool K10Run = false;
  bool K11Run = false;
  int JR = 5;
  int JL = 5;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
}

void loop() {


if ( digitalRead(K10) == LOW ){
  
  bool K10Run = true;
  
} else {

  bool K10Run = false;
  
}


if ( digitalRead(K11) == LOW ){
  
  bool K11Run = true;
  
} else {

  bool K11Run = false;
  
}


if ( analogRead(JRY) < 1100 ) {    //
  
  JR = 1;     //przód
  
} else if ( analogRead(JRY) > 1900 ){

  JR = 2;     //tył  
  
} else if ( analogRead(JRX) < 1100 ){
  
  JR = 3;     //lewo
  
} else if ( analogRead(JRX) > 1900 ){

  JR = 4;     //prawo
  
} else {

  JR = 5;     //stop
  
}


if ( analogRead(JLY) < 1100 ) {
  
  JL = 1;     //przód
  
} else if ( analogRead(JLY) > 1900 ){

  JL = 2;     //tył  
  
} else if ( analogRead(JLX) < 1100 ){
  
  JL = 3;     //lewo
  
} else if ( analogRead(JLX) > 1900 ){

  JL = 4;     //prawo
  
} else {

  JL = 5;     //stop
  
}

Serial.print(JR);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(JL);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(K10Run);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(K11Run);
Serial.print("\t");
delay(100);

}
```

Comment: `JR` and `JL` are only defined in `setup` but you're trying to reference them in `loop`. You might want to look up "variable scope in C++" for basic information on how variables work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring JR as a local variable in void setup. If you want to use in void loop() you have to declare it as a global variable. You will have the same issue with the other ones, so you have to do the same with JR, JL, K10, etc...

You can try this code:

```
#define K10 14
#define K11 15
#define JRY A2
#define JRX A3
#define JLY A4
#define JLX A5

bool K10Run = false;
bool K11Run = false;
int JR = 5;
int JL = 5;

void setup() {

  pinMode(K10, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(K11, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(JRY, INPUT);
  pinMode(JRX, INPUT);
  pinMode(JLY, INPUT);
  pinMode(JLX, INPUT);

  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
}

void loop() {


if ( digitalRead(K10) == LOW ){
  
  K10Run = true;
  
} else {

  K10Run = false;
  
}


if ( digitalRead(K11) == LOW ){
  
  K11Run = true;
  
} else {

  K11Run = false;
  
}


if ( analogRead(JRY) < 1100 ) {    //
  
  JR = 1;     //przód
  
} else if ( analogRead(JRY) > 1900 ){

  JR = 2;     //tył  
  
} else if ( analogRead(JRX) < 1100 ){
  
  JR = 3;     //lewo
  
} else if ( analogRead(JRX) > 1900 ){

  JR = 4;     //prawo
  
} else {

  JR = 5;     //stop
  
}


if ( analogRead(JLY) < 1100 ) {
  
  JL = 1;     //przód
  
} else if ( analogRead(JLY) > 1900 ){

  JL = 2;     //tył  
  
} else if ( analogRead(JLX) < 1100 ){
  
  JL = 3;     //lewo
  
} else if ( analogRead(JLX) > 1900 ){

  JL = 4;     //prawo
  
} else {

  JL = 5;     //stop
  
}

Serial.print(JR);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(JL);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(K10Run);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(K11Run);
Serial.print("\t");
delay(100);

}
```